# Have you ever been so close ... things suddenly all go wrong

Tags: tense, present-perfect, present-simple, aspect

The following is an interesting combination of the present perfect in the first clause and the present simple in the second. They supposedly refer to the same experience. Why is this mismatch okay? Any logical explanations?

> **Have** you ever **been** so close to achieving your goal but things suddenly all **go** wrong?

Comment: +1 for another interesting question. I can't put my finger on it, but it's something to do with discourse style, similar to how when telling a story that happened in the past, you have licence to switch to present tenses to make it feel more "immediate" to the audience. Possibly of interest, the tense choice for the "go" verb is between simple past and present simple. No perfect tense is possible there.

Comment: Don't forget that present perfect and present simple are both *present* tenses!

Comment: @stangdon The catch is that the present simple (generally) describes habitual events, which is not the case in the OP.

Comment: @stangdon It'd be more natural to use simple past there than present simple.

Comment: While it's a question about the past, it doesn't refer to a specific past event - *have you ever*. The first part sets a scene and asks about a hypothetical event in it.

Comment: It's habitual if things are always going wrong. Or could be a case of using present tense for vividly narrating past events: "You must have experienced this: you think you're happy and then all of a sudden everything goes wrong."

Comment: Is the following okay? "You must have this experience: you **have been** close to achieving your goal and then all of a sudden everything **goes** wrong."

Comment: @Apollyon No. You should use simple present for both verbs: "*You **are** close... everything **goes** wrong*", or both simple past: "*You **were** close... everything **went** wrong*".

Comment: @gotube Thank you. Is this okay? "**Are** you ever close to achieving your goal, but all of a sudden everything **goes** wrong"?

Comment: @Apollyon Better with "*... **a** goal*", because "your goal" suggests that you have only ever had one goal in life, but I believe your question refers to whatever goal you happen to have at that moment when everything goes wrong. Now the semantics are good, but a more natural phrasing is, "***Do you ever find yourself** close to achieving a goal, but...*"

Comment: @gotube Thank you. Your version is probably what most learners would find natural and have no problems with, unlike the sentence in the OP.

Comment: @Apollyon The OP version is natural too. My version and the OP version are suitable to different contexts. The OP version sounds like someone introducing a story about everything going wrong by inviting the listener to identify with them. My version sounds like someone who's trying to sell something by inviting the listener to feel bad.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that English speakers are not very strict with tenses, so the "rules" can be quite flexible.

In fact, your sentence could be written with consistent tenses<sup>1</sup>:

> Have you ever been so close to achieving your goal but things have suddenly all gone wrong?<sup>2</sup>

However, because the first clause seems to establish a specific time (i.e., when the person has been close to achieving a goal), the second clause seems to work better with a simple (non-perfect) tense. It could even work well with the simple past tense:

> Have you ever been so close to achieving your goal but things suddenly all went wrong?

Here are some more examples in which it's unclear whether the first clause establishes a specific time so that the second clause could be in the present perfect, simple present, or simple past:

> I've tried to whistle that tune several times, but I've always gotten it wrong / but I always get it wrong / but I always got it wrong.

> I've often tried to sleep when I haven't been tired / when I'm not tired / when I wasn't tired.

> I've never mixed red with blue so that they've formed purple / so that they form purple / so that they formed purple.

---

<sup>1</sup> For simplicity, I won't distinguish among "tense", "aspect", etc.

<sup>2</sup> I think that this would read better with "when" instead of "but" (no matter which tenses are used), but that's a separate issue.

Comment: English is fairly strict about tense choice. This just happens to be a context where there's some flexibility, and there's a rule that governs it. That rule is what the OP is after.

Comment: @gotube I suppose that "strict" is rather subjective, but I think that English tenses are not as strict as many askers on this site assume. That's the main point I was trying to make (perhaps not so successfully).

Comment: This sentence is incorrect: *"*Yesterday I **am** close to achieving my goal, but things suddenly **go** wrong*", and yet the OP's sentence is correct. This necessarily means *there is a rule* that allows the use of present simple to refer to an event at a finished past time, and it's worth exploring what that rule is. Explaining the OP's sentence away by saying "*English speakers are not very strict with tenses...*" is simply incorrect.

Comment: @gotube My understanding of OP's question is that he or she isn't asking about why present tense is used but why it's possible to mix perfect with non-perfect tenses ("Why is this mismatch okay?"). Perhaps we understand the question differently.

Answer (score 1):

> Have you ever been so close to achieving your goal ***but*** things suddenly all go wrong?

The right answer here is that you have two independent clauses in the sentence separated with a conjunction (but). Another example would be when someone gets hired at a company, they might be introduced thus on their first week:

> Pat has worked as an assassin for a variety of organizations ***and*** now they are bringing their hands-on personnel skills to our HR department.

Or:

> Pat can take this assignment ***because*** he's done this kind of work dozens of times before.

The second clause I the first example I give can be expected to be (and is) present continuous because they are actively in the process of joining the company.

Our friends at the Cambridge Dictionary provide support for this in British English grammar in their [article on clauses](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/clauses), but they don't provide a rule along the lines of "if (x situation), then verbs may have mismatched tenses" that I found in my looking for one.

If one is looking for a hard-and-fast rule for why tense mismatch is allowed in some cases but not others, it might be possible to find a book from what's seen as an authoritative source describing it, but the English language is *descriptive*, rather than *prescriptive*. There's no single governing body like the [Académie Française](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acad%C3%A9mie_Fran%C3%A7aise) (French Academy), which has authority over "proper" French, or the [Asociación de Academias de la Lengua Española](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_of_Academies_of_the_Spanish_Language) (Association of the Spanish Language), which are a collection of similarly minded organizations around the world that focus on maintaining the consistency of the Spanish language.

Rather, Standard English just kind of wings it, because there's 1) there's no single Standard English, and 2) no single place that (successfully) defines rules for it. Frankly, something in English is grammatically correct once enough people use it that it enters regular usage, which can be frustrating for English language learners -- but is also a pretty egalitarian way of operating!

If you're interested in the history of how English came to be and why it's so loosey-goosey, I highly recommend [The Last Lingua Franca: English until the return of Babel](https://www.worldcat.org/title/last-lingua-franca-english-until-the-return-of-babel/oclc/645705448) by Nicholas Ostler, as it does a deep dive of why English became what it is, while also looking at other languages (namely Latin) that have served the same purpose and have similar origins.

Comment: The OP's sentence in statement form is incorrect: "*I **have been** so close to achieving my goals, but everything **goes** wrong.*" If the answer were as simple as the conjunction allowing tense changes, then this sentence too would be correct, but it's not. This question requires a rule that explains why the OP's question is correct, but my statement version is incorrect.

Comment: On the contrary, OP's modified sentence that you wrote is fine, and could be expected to be seen in writing or heard in speech, e.g. by someone who's at their wits' end. If you can specify what you think is wrong with the sentence you put, I'd be curious to see it.

Could it be written in a way that flows or sounds better or more poetically? Sure; the sentence would be served by a **then** following **but**. That would change the meaning to "things go wrong as a result of my being close to achieving my goals" from "things go wrong whether or not I am close to achieving my goals."

Comment: Then we just disagree. I can't think of a context where my modified version is acceptable, and it certainly doesn't work the way the OP's sentence does.